# repeat customer count month wise in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm loking for one logic that might be not accepatable.

But my requirement is I want count of customers(NewCustomers, repeatCustomers) on the basis of previous and current month

Like from this data I want

```
DATE       NAME
2016-01-01 A
2016-01-01 B
2016-01-01 C
2016-01-05 E
2016-01-05 F
2016-01-25 G
2016-01-25 H
2016-02-25 A
2016-02-25 E
2016-02-10 X
2016-02-11 Y
2016-02-13 F
```

Output like this

```
MONTH    NewCustomer     RepeatCustomer   CustomerCount of refernece month (Like here is JAN)


FEB       2              3                7
```

Same will go for next months

Any suggestion ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the reference month is, but you can get the first two columns by combining the *first* time you see a customer with who visits in each month:

```
select date_format(c.date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       count(distinct c.name) as NumCustomers,
       sum(case when date_format(c.date, '%Y-%m') <> date_format(cc.start_date, '%Y-%m')
                then 1 else 0
           end) as NumRepeatCustomers
from customers c join
     (select c.name, min(c.date) as start_date
      from customers c
      group by c.name
     ) cc
     on c.name = cc.name
group by date_format(c.date, '%Y-%m')
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: Like when year starts, So in Jan there would be no repeat customers all will be new, In FEB could be if jan customers come in feb as well. So in that case jan is my Ref month for finding repeat customers.